# What would it be like if the supernova ASAS-SN-15lh was in the Milky way?

Tags: astrophysics, supernova

I'm simply wondering what it would be like if the super nova ASAS-SN-15lh (http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/01/universe-s-most-luminous-supernova-was-50-times-brighter-milky-way) was in our milky way, Would it bring to earth as much light as the moon ? Could it be dangerous for the eye or anything else ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia, from New Scientist

> According to Krzysztof Stanek of Ohio State University, one of the
>   principal investigators at ASAS-SN, "If it was in our own galaxy, it
>   would shine brighter than the full moon; there would be no night, and
>   it would be easily seen during the day."[6]

[6] https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn28772-weve-found-the-brightest-ever-supernova-but-cant-explain-it/

Comment: Could it be dangerous for the eye or anything else ?